# Debugging fortran code in Eclipse with Photran and GDB debugger: missing symbols

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, fortran90, photran

I have a program, written in fortran90, previously successfully compiled on a compaq compiler and working, that I'm now trying to compile with gfortran. I can compile the code to an .exe and run it. It works fine until a certain point in the routine and then an error is thrown.

My current configuration:

- Windows 7
- Eclipse Juno with CDT
- Photran
- Cygwin installation with gfortran compiler and GDB debugger (gdb.exe)
- Configurations for the debugger:

  - GDB command set: Standard (Windows)
  - Protocol: mi
  - Shared libraries: don't load shared library symbols automatically (when activating this, no changes are noted).

When running the debug command I get the following output:

```
.gdbinit: No such file or directory.
Reading symbols from /cygdrive/c/Users/thys/Documents/doctoraat/12_in   progress/Hamfem/Debug/Hamfem.exe...done.
auto-solib-add on
Undefined command: "auto-solib-add".  Try "help".
Warning: C:/Users/thys/Documents/doctoraat/12_in progress/Hamfem/Hamfem/in: No such     file or directory.
[New Thread 5816.0x1914]
[New Thread 5816.0x654]
```

Basicly that leaves me with 2 questions:

1. Where can I find the .gdbinit file in the cygwin installation?
2. Are there any other possible errors in my setup, or points to think about?

Comment: Do you have spaces in names of directories or files?

Comment: no, made sure that no spaces were in the names or files

Comment: What is the warning message then? **C:/Users/thys/Documents/doctoraat/12_in progress/Hamfem/Hamfem/in : No such     file or directory.**
As for `.gdbinit`, it contains the commands for `gdb` to execute upon startup. You can create it in the directory where your program to debug resides.

See this linky: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/638553/

It makes sense sometimes to read docs: `man gdb`, `info gdb`.

Comment: I switched to gfortran and gdb on a linux machine. So didn't find the best configuration for Cygwin-Gfortran-GDB (and eclipse) on windows for developping fortran software.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the debugging information when compiling? When using gdb in console it shouldn't be a problem, except looking at memory addresses and a lot of gibberish, but there could be complications from using Eclipse...

Comment: It turned out to be indeed the debugging information that was missing. The errors were declaration errors of do-loops, where the gnu-compiler is rather strickt

Comment: Nice. I guess this is some option in Eclipse... Would you tell me where it is?

Comment: There's no better reward for the help than accepting an answer.

Comment: When trying this solution I got some new errors. Set aside the work for a while, but picked it up again recently. Debugging information is present, no spaces in names and still no solution.